# Android : multiple images required for an application

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

Is it ok to have lot of images in your application .. If an app has say 1K photos and if i have that images in hdpi,ldpi,mdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi .. it will be a size issue for the app ..

So it's better to have a web view loading image from url or storing images in app?

Comment: Why dont you synchronize images from the web on the first run of your app? Loading will be faster and sometimes you dont even need a internet connection later.

Comment: you should find a balance. If you have 1k of photos you better to download them. If you have 2 photos, you better to put them in apk.

Comment: Or you can try storing it just in xhdpi if possible? As android resizes the images automatically if no images is present in other folders

Comment: @PirateCube.: can u help me get a good link in finding how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the images are not really excessively large, it's better to store in an app, I think:

- you won't need internet permission
- this will be much faster to display to the user which will result in a better user experience

Comment: I'd add that loading image inside a webview is not really great (performance issues), just grab it and load it in any image view using stuffs like : http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html